# Deployment of Machine Learning models on KAFKA

Tags: machine-learning, apache-kafka

How can I deploying ML models on Kafka?

Answer (score 0):

Kafka does not (reasonably) "host" machine learning models. So you cannot "deploy them onto" it.

Instead, you can embed them within Stream Processing libraries such as Kafka Streams, Spark, [or KSQL](https://www.confluent.io/blog/machine-learning-with-python-jupyter-ksql-tensorflow/).

But, if you can define a common serialization format for ML models, then those could be stored in topics, but then you'd need some consumption model and "recompile" your model somehow, based on that.